# dynamic write and read from appsettings in .netcore class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration, configuration-files

We have a class library which has appsettings.json file for configuration.We need to write data dynamically and read it.We searched for solution but we need startup.cs for it to implement whereas we don't have in class library.Please suggest some solution or easy way to achieve it.We are using .net core and a worker service where this class library is called.

Answer (score 0):

> We have a class library which has appsettings.json file for configuration.We need to write data dynamically and read it

If you'd like to dynamically read and write data from a json file within your class library, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
var _filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "appsettings_for_classlibrary.json");

JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_filepath));

((JValue)o1["Item1"][0]["Ival"]).Value = "test";

o1.Add("NewItem", "Test Value");

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = System.IO.File.CreateText(_filepath))
using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(file))
{
    o1.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please set the *Build Action* to *content* and *Copy to Output Directory* to either *Copy always* or *Copy if newer* for that json file, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYiNH.png).

Comment: Hi Han,thanks for the reply.Your code serves the basic need of ours like read and write to json file in class library. However,we are looking to write to  appsettings.json we want to use configuration provided in .net core.

Comment: `we want to use configuration provided in .net core` Hi @Gani.one, if you check [the definition of JsonConfigurationProvider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt5EP.png), you would find built-in `JsonConfigurationProvider` does not implement the saving of the data into the configuration file.